# How to escape the duplicity in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, coding-style

My experience and good books had taught me that repeating of the same thing in code is bad. But when I use Android views, I often repeat the same thing even 4 times:

twice in XML:

```
<LinearLayout                    -1
    android:id="@+id/lila"
    ...
>
    ...
</LineraLayout                   -2
```

and twice in code:

```
     3               4
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
```

Of course, when I have to change the type of the view, I have to do it in four places, what causes errors. In the XML I could use refactoring to change simultaneously the class of layout or even of a view or widget. But that doesn't help much, because the most dangerous disrepancy, not catched by the compiler, can appear between code and XML. And later I have to waste time and look for the source of a runtime error.

Are there other possibilities to address views from layouts? Not so dangerous?

If not, do you know some trick to change or at least check all these places simultaneously?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that could help you (depending on case, of what you want to do for example with your `LinearLayout`) is declaring your `Views` as generic as possible. Here, in your example you could keep your `LinearLayout` as, `ViewGroup` if you do not need any `LinearLayout` specific methods. So, if later you decided to change that layout in xml, in `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`, etc, you will not get any cast problems.

You could take the same approach for `Buttons`, or other `Views`, depending on what methods you use on them. For example if you just set an `onClickListener` on your `Button`, you can keep a refrence to it just to an `View`, (ex. `View button=findViewById(R.id.button);`), and later you could change it in a `ImageView` maybe, and still don't have any cast problems, since they both are extended from `View`.

So the solution in big lines : use a class at the highest `level` as you can.

Comment: Thank you. But it is a pity that there are no tricks to make simultaneous changes in code and xml.

Answer (score 2):

for xml layout reusing, you can use include and merge layouts.
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

As for Activity, you must use super class references as far as possible, because it provides you a flexibility to change specific object class.

Like instead of using we can

ViewGroup ll=(ViewGroup ) findViewById(R.id.lila);

now this can address relative layout, linear layout, table layout, etc.